# ¿Cómo crear un diagrama condicional?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo un gran dataframe:

```
>>>print(stats.shape)
(14480, 4)

>>> stats.head(3)
    cos_success     euc_success     cos_result  euc_result
0   False           False           0.099913    1.541779
1   False           True            0.073723    1.115237
2   True            False           0.068415    1.095448
```

Y quiero crear dos diagramas, uno para `cos` y el otro para`euc`, con dos curvas cada una, una para la distribución de`False` y la otra para la distribución `True`.
El objetivo final es encontrar un umbral desde el cual uno pueda decir que `cos` o `euc` pasan al False.

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que tengo la solucion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Cosinus similarity
# Create a color if the group is "B"
my_color=np.where(stats['cos_success'] == False, 'orange', 'skyblue')

# Sort the dataframe by target
target_0 = stats.loc[stats['cos_success'] == True]
target_1 = stats.loc[stats['cos_success'] == False]
sns.distplot(target_0['cos_result'].dropna(), hist=False, rug=True, label= 'True')
sns.distplot(target_1['cos_result'].dropna(), hist=False, rug=True, label= 'False')
plt.show()

# euclidian similarity
my_color=np.where(stats['euc_success'] == False, 'orange', 'skyblue')

target_0 = stats.loc[stats['euc_success'] == True]
target_1 = stats.loc[stats['euc_success'] == False]
sns.distplot(target_0['euc_result'].dropna(), hist=False, rug=True, label= 'True')
sns.distplot(target_1['euc_result'].dropna(), hist=False, rug=True, label= 'False')
plt.show()
```

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]